Excel - VBA Custom function, detect color & sum
This is my first request, so sorry if something is incorrect.
I'm working on Excel 2019 and created a custom function:
' Color & Sum
Function ContColor(InputRange As Range) As Double

    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sum As Double
    Dim colorPD As Long

    sum = 0
    
    colorPD = RGB(153, 255, 102) ' My Color
    
    For Each cell In InputRange
            If cell.Interior.Color = colorPD Then
                sum = sum + cell.Value
            End If
   
    Next cell
    
    ContColor = CLng(sum)

End Function

Now, I would like to change the optional colorPD to a default color like this:
Function ContColor(InputRange As Range, Optional colorPd As Long = RGB(153, 255, 102)) As Double
transforming the function like this:
Function ContColor(InputRange As Range, Optional colorPd As Long = RGB(153, 255, 102)) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim sum As Double

    sum = 0
    
    For Each cell In InputRange
            If cell.Interior.Color = colorPD Then
                sum = sum + cell.Value
            End If
   
    Next cell
    
    ContColor = CLng(sum)

End Function

But I get error. Someone help me?

Welcome to SO. Please specify what error are you getting and how are you calling this UDF and what are the values of the arguments and what should be the expected output

You cannot use a function like RGB to specify a default value for colorPD. You have to provide a constant value., in this case 6750105.  And that's it what you get as a compiler message, right?
